# Prioritizing asynchronous jquery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 asynchronous jQuery ajax call in my code. They are called one after the other from a javascript file. Now what happens is that the first call is made when the page is loaded. The first call takes around 60 seconds to complete. But depending on the user input the second call can be made even before the completion of the first call.

Now the 2nd call only takes around 4 seconds to complete. I want to set priority in the second call such that when it is made it should be treated with higher priority and it should be completed ahead of the 1st call.

Please let me know if this is possible and if yes then how.

Answer (score 0):

Make this priority at the serverside. Once a file is beeing loaded by the client it is not a good method to try to stop it, serverside code will be ran anyway. So, do some checks in serversideocode to notice if the 60 second request is done with a specific id, if so, pause that code and push in the small one.

For instance you can have a temporary table in sql. With active requests. saving progress of files and removing when done. Use it to keep track.

Comment: How can I pause an ajax call in a php file? Any idea will be really appreciated. Also consider the fact that both ajax calls are being made to the same php file. Though we can seperate them as well if necessary.

Comment: You can not. But if you have one "file call" that takes 60 seconds, and another that takes 3 seconds to perform on the severside, before it returns the answer to the ajax request. You can do checks to ensure that the 60 second procedures in php are paused to give room for the 3 second call functions. If that one is given priority, it will finish before the 60 second version all the time in the javascript. Even if the 60 second version is started before. Now this dosnt have to be doable, but it "might" be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

If you want call 2 to not wait for call 1, just put the ajax calls one after the other.  The second call will execute without waiting for the first to finish.

If you want second call to be executed after response from the first then put the second ajax call in the .done() function.

Comment: The first call is made as soon as the page is loaded and the 2nd call depends on user clicking on a specific button. So I can't decide the order of the call in code. I hope you can understand the situation.

Comment: When user clicks on a button, set a boolean variable.  When a response from first call is complete, you will only act on the response from call 1 based on the boolean value.

Comment: My problem here is that when the 1st call is running and it has run for a period of 15 or 20 seconds depending on when the user clicks the button, then after clicking 2nd call is made. I want this 2nd call to finish ahead of the 1st call. But currently it rather waits for the 1st call to finish and then it gets completed as well.